# Why are there github projects with an empty list of contributors?

Tags: git, github

In some Github projects the list of contributors is empty. What's the reason for this?

Example:

- Using Github API v3 — https://api.github.com/repos/rnauber/pipepanic-android/contributors
- Using Github Website — https://github.com/rnauber/pipepanic-android/graphs/contributors

Comment: Authors of commits are not matched to Github users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you clone that repo and look at `git log`, you'll see, that author of all commits is `olg <x>`. Github can't match e-mail address `x` to any of registered users.